# onclick valye equal to html number

Tags: jquery, calculator

i creat a calculator and i want that when i click on a number it will give me the inner html value for i not need to creat a lot of variables

for example:

if html - 8 on click this div will bring value of 8 and so on

```
$('number').on('click', function() {
$(this).html(value);
});
```

here is the link code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/24/

will be happy for any suggestions

thanks,

Comment: use `.` for the class selectors `$(".number")`

Comment: There's no javascript at all in your fiddle. Have you tried writing anything?

Comment: @jonhopkins thanks for exploring my question! yes i have tried many thing but wanted to leave it clear to get the wright and clear answer

Comment: @alonblack That's fair reasoning for leaving it blank. But for future reference, it helps to include in your question an attempt that didn't work. Many times it turns out that the existing code is very close to the solution. Plus it's always nice to have a base to start with when trying to help someone solve their problem :)

Comment: @jonhopkins no problem i will keep it in mind, thanks for ur time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = 0;
var plus = 0;
$('.number').on('click', function () {
    result = this.innerHTML;
    $('#result').append(result);
});
$('#plus').on('click', function () {
    plus = parseInt($('#result').html());
    $('#result').html('');
});
$('#equal').on('click', function () {
    var equal = plus + parseInt($('#result').html());
    $('#result').html(equal);
    plus = 0;
});
$('#clear').on('click', function () {
    $('#result').html('');
});
```

### **Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asGTp/3/)**

You had forgoten a `.` in the class selector, and the you can use:

`$(this).html()` or event better: `this.innerHTML`

Comment: thanks very much!! really helpful! how can i show only 1 number in the "result" screen?

Comment: @alonblack, you mean one number att the time? like 1 and not 10, or?

Comment: yes that exactly what i want! to limit the number for user can not press multiple numbers only one number at a time but still can do: 9+9+9+9...=

Comment: did u saw my last comment here pleas?

Comment: i don't want to posibble more than 1 number in the "result" screen: 1+9 and not posibble: 11111+9;

Comment: @alonblack, yes did you see the demo on my last comment?

Comment: sure, but still i can type there multiple numbers

Comment: @alonblack why did you remove accepted answer from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First, you missed the `.` in your selector to indicate a class.

Your `value` is the clicked button's text, `$(this).text()`.

`trim()` removes trailing spaces.

You must append that result to your output div.

```
$('.number').on('click', function() {
    var resultDiv = $('#result'); //The output.
    var current = resultDiv.html(); //Get the current html.
    resultDiv.html(current + $(this).text().trim()); //Append clicked text.
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/26/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.number').click(function(){
       $('#result').append(parseInt($(this).text()));
    });
});
```

JSFiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/31/

Comment: thank you very much! i want to pisibble just 1 number every time for example: 9 + 9 ; and not posibble : 99 + 9;

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.number').on('click', function() {
alert($(this).text());//also use html
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/30/)**